# Path of jar: URI

Tags: java, networking, jar, uri

can anyone please explain me, what does it *exactly* mean 'path' in terminology of URI?

I mean, when I have URI

```
file:///somedir/somefile
```

the method `getURI` on `java.net.URI` returns simply

```
/somedir/somefile
```

When I use URI with HTTP protocol as follows

```
http://localhost/some-ehm-dir/somefile
```

it's not suprisingly, that the path is

```
/some-ehm-dir/somefile
```

But, when I try to get path from `jar:`, it returns `null` in each combination I tried:

```
jar:file:///somedir/somejarfile.jar
jar:file:///somedir/somejarfile.jar!somedir/somefile
jar:http:///whatever/some-ehm-dir/somejarfile.jar
...
```

I found that URI syntax looks like:

```
jar:<url>!/[<entry>]
```

Does it mean, that `jar` protocol has path not defined and returns `null` for every URL?

(I am asking because I am using class `SimpleJavaFileObject`, which requires uri with non-null path.)

Comment: Where did you find this specification for URI syntax?  It looks like you are specifying 2 protocols: `jar` and either `file` or `http`.

Comment: I found this on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes) which refers to [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/jar) or [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) with the same content.